# How can I create polygons that are on the edge of point data and angle the polygons based on numerical angle data generated from flow direction?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon-creation, arcgis-10.5, direction, angles

ArcGIS 3D Analyst 10.5.0.

I have a set of well locations and I would like to define the groundwater capture zone based on the groundwater velocity and the direction of flow. I calculated flow direction using Flow Direction in Hydrology, under Spatial Analyst. Now I want to use this direction data to "draw" polygons at the edge of my well points in the opposite direction of flow.

How can I create a set of rectangle polygons that have an edge centered on point locations and are angled according to a numerical angle I have added to the point data?